# Tracing functions in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I was searching about how to trace function graphs, but not only linear ones, I know how to plot with simple points, they are the linear ones like this one below:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
_=plt.plot([4,7],[5,7],color ='w')
_=plt.plot([4,7],[7,7],color ='w')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_facecolor('xkcd:red')

plt.show()
```

then after a bit of searching, I've found this [code](https://glowingpython.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-plot-function-using-matplotlib.html?showComment=1532678579612#c8360503690496493446):

```
import pylab
import numpy

x = numpy.linspace(-15,15,100) # 100 linearly spaced numbers
y = numpy.sin(x)/x # computing the values of sin(x)/x

# compose plot
pylab.plot(x,y) # sin(x)/x
pylab.plot(x,y,'co') # same function with cyan dots
pylab.plot(x,2*y,x,3*y) # 2*sin(x)/x and 3*sin(x)/x
pylab.show() # show the plot
```

That works perfectly! But what I'm wondering is: do we really need to use standard functions that have defined by Numpy?( like sin(x)/x here ) Or can we define a function ourselves and use it in Numpy function too, like x**3?

Comment: Have yout tried writing `y=x**3` yourself?

Comment: Wow, thanks, mate!, That's awesome! I tried many things, but I've forgot about removing (Numpy.) part, , sometimes you can't see something that stands infront of you :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved issue, Thanks FlyingTeller

An example of y=x**3 graph:

```
import pylab
import numpy

x = numpy.linspace(-15,15,100) # 100 linearly spaced numbers
y = x**3 # we change this to tracer graphs as we want 

# compose plot
pylab.plot(x,y) 
pylab.show()
```